# Cannot run SP2013 workflows after migration to SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016, workflow-manager

we have a single SP2016 VM, with SQL database on different VM.
I have done the migration by detach-attach and mounting content database.
There are few simple emailing workflows - some SP2010, some SP2013 version.

I have configured workflow manager in all defaults, but I am having trouble with getting SP2013 workflows to run.
SP2010 work fine, I can re-save SP2013 WF in SP Designer, but they are not working.
On item update, on new item, no WF status shown in list view. 
I tried to ran a workflow with powershell, which doesn't show an error, but doesn't work either.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out somehow, but not sure which action accually hepled.

I was following [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vincent_runge/2014/01/07/troubleshooting-actions-for-sharepoint-2013-workflows/) and in some point manual run started working, but workflow got stuck on change or item creation.

That turned out to be some anomaly in my user account... after manually logging off and on sharepoint, it started working on item change/creation.

I had to re-save all other SP2013 workflows and it seem to be all working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the new SharePoint 2013 workflows are working in your SharePoint 2016 environment? Try to create a new workflow and check again.

Try to run the [Register-Spworkflowservice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/register-spworkflowservice?view=sharepoint-ps) command and check again.

If the issue exists, try to install SPD 2013 SP1 for SharePoint Designer and check again.

Comment: New workflow gets created, but not running on item change, as I configured.
Registering service makes no change, goes without error.
I have SPD in higher version than SP1.